# Docker save not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: docker

I am newbie to Docker areana. After couple of hours, I could build docker for my requirement and I am very excited.

I want to move this docker and load it on my AWS instance.  To do this I tried docker save command, but got error.

docker save -o . captom
rename .docker_temp_924538595 .: device or resource busy

I made sure that docker is stopped.  I even restarted daemon but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake in this...

I supplied "." (current directory) as output path, assuming that docker save will create file(s) here.  But it required file path (not directory) ..